# Matching days and hours

Tags: php, arrays, days, hour

I want to Group Days and Hours from this:

```
Mon  : array(9:00AM - 11:00AM, 1:00pm-6pm)
Tue  : array(8:00AM - 11:00AM,12:00pm-6pm)
Wed  : array(9:00AM - 11:00AM, 1:00pm-6pm)
Thu  : array(9:00AM - 11:00AM,1:00pm-6pm)
Fri  : array(9:00AM - 12:00PM,1:00pm-6pm)
Sat  : array(9:00AM - 7:00PM)
Sun  : array(9:00AM - 12:00AM,1:00pm-6pm)
```

expected result:

```
Mon,wed,thu - 9:00AM - 11:00aM
              1:00pm-6pm
tue :         8:00AM - 11:00am
              12:00pm-6pm   
fri,sun -     9:00AM - 12:00PM
              1:00pm-6pm
sat:          9:00AM -7:00pm
```

```
Below is the code which I'm trying to work out.

    $open_Hours = array(
            'Mon' => array('9:00AM - 11:00AM', '1:00pm-6pm'),
            'Tue' =>array('8:00AM - 11:00AM', '12:00pm-6pm'),
            'Wed' =>  array('9:00AM - 11:00AM', '1:00pm-6pm'),
            'Thu' => array('9:00AM - 11:00AM','1:00pm-6pm'),
            'Fri' => array('9:00AM - 12:00PM','1:00pm-6pm'),
            'Sat' => array('9:00AM - 7:00PM'),
            'Sun' => array('9:00AM - 12:00AM','1:00pm-6pm')
        );

     foreach($open_Hours as $k => $v){

            $open_array[$v][] = $k;
        }
     foreach($open_array as $time => $days){

             echo implode(",", $days) . " " . $time . PHP_EOL;

     }
```

Comment: How are you getting above array?

Comment: Code is not working. Any your initial code and stayed things are not matching. In Code you have not mentioned the evening time for Mon and other days as it exists in above. Please check both things. Then you can compare the value of array. Though matching with each other can be clubbed. I am ready to help you in writing code if you need me.

Comment: ** i want output :Mon,wed,thu - 9:00AM - 11:00aM
              1:00pm-6pm
tue :         8:00AM - 11:00am
              12:00pm-6pm   **
fri,sun -     9:00AM - 12:00PM
              1:00pm-6pm
sat:          9:00AM -7:00pm

Comment: @– Charanjeet Singh  : help me

Comment: change `$open_array[$v][] = $k;` to `foreach ($val as $v1) { $open_array[$v1][] = $k;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
<?php
    $open_Hours = array(
        'Mon' => array('9:00AM - 11:00AM', '1:00pm - 6pm'),
        'Tue' => array('8:00AM - 11:00AM', '12:00pm - 6pm'),
        'Wed' => array('9:00AM - 11:00AM', '1:00pm - 6pm'),
        'Thu' => array('9:00AM - 11:00AM','1:00pm - 6pm'),
        'Fri' => array('9:00AM - 12:00PM','1:00pm - 6pm'),
        'Sat' => array('9:00AM - 7:00PM'),
        'Sun' => array('9:00AM - 12:00PM','1:00pm - 6pm')
    );

    $open_array = array();
    foreach($open_Hours as $day => $periods) {
        if(!isset($open_array[serialize($periods)]))
            $open_array[serialize($periods)] = array();
        $open_array[serialize($periods)][] = $day;
    }

    foreach($open_array as $times => $days) {
        $times = unserialize($times);
        $days = implode(",", $days);
        for($i=0;$i<count($times); $i++) {
            if($i == 0) {
                echo $days;
                echo str_repeat(' ', ((strlen($days)>12)?0:(12-strlen($days)));
            } else {
                echo str_repeat(' ', 12);
            }
            echo '- ' . $times[$i] . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Mon,Wed,Thu - 9:00AM - 11:00AM
            - 1:00pm - 6pm
Tue         - 8:00AM - 11:00AM
            - 12:00pm - 6pm
Fri,Sun     - 9:00AM - 12:00PM
            - 1:00pm - 6pm
Sat         - 9:00AM - 7:00PM
```

It makes use of serialize() as the array index so that you can group by multiple sets of hours properly.

Let me know if you need any further help or explanation.